# Can't write in file - python

Tags: python-3.x

```
l = []

print("We will need some information first.")
t_first_name = input("User First Name: ").lower()
while len(t_first_name) == 0 or t_first_name == ' ':
    t_first_name = input("User First Name: ").lower()

while len(t_last_name) == 0 or t_last_name == ' ':
    t_last_name = input("User Surname: ").lower()

f_n_up = t_first_name.upper()
l_n_up = t_last_name.upper()
f_n_title = t_first_name.title()
l_n_title = t_last_name.title()

l.append(t_first_name) # Lowercase
l.append(t_last_name)
l.append(f_n_up) # Uppercase 
l.append(l_n_up)
l.append(f_n_title) # The first letter is uppercase 
l.append(l_n_title)

f = open("p_list.txt", "a")
for x in l:
    print(x)
    if len(x) >= 5:
        f.write(x)
        print("test")
```

It will show the `print` lines and it create the file, but when i open it, i don't find any words in it.

It will ask for the user name and then make a list about him, adding it to a list `l` and then make a loop inside it and write the string in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You should either call `f.close()` or `f.flush()` for the data to be actually written to the file.

Another (and better) solution is to use [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to handle the file opening and closing for you:

```
with open('p_list.txt', 'a') as f:
    for x in l:
        print(x)
        if len(x) >= 5:
            f.write(x)
            print("test")
```